# F#: Why can't I use optional parameters in loose functions?

Tags: f#, optional-parameters

Why can't I use optional parameters in loose functions defined with "let"?

Why are they only allowed in member functions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suspect they are provided only for compatibility with .NET functions.  They aren't something you encounter in functional languages.  The problem with an optional parameter is you can't curry it.  If a function f's second parameter is optional, what is

let g = f x
?

Is it a function taking one argument, or a value obtained by evaluating f on x plus the default second parameter?

Answer (score 4):

It is allowed in OCaml. Therefore it should be possible to implement it in F#.

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lablexamples.html#sec43

I guess it has been omitted for simplicity in F#.