# How to define optional parameters in F# modules?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to re-write a tiny C# lib in F# and I've encountered an error. I'm trying to define optional parameters for a method in a module but the compiler says "Optional arguments are only permitted on type members".

I've checked [why you can't use them in loose functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946159/f-why-cant-i-use-optional-parameters-in-loose-functions) but [when typing `static member` or `member` I get another error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56597149/1275774) instead.

```
module Kingdom =
    let Rule (?years : int) =
        ()
```

I thought this was going to wor kas it's how I understood you type it, after reading the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters) article about it.

Comment: The docs link you provided states 'optional parameters are permitted only on members, not on functions created by using let bindings'. I don't believe you can have an optional parameter on a top level function in F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13419343/1275774) to define the "static class" you can add `member` to it. And then you can use optional parameters. The class will show up as a normal static class in C#.

```
[<AbstractClass; Sealed>]
type Kingdom private () =
    static member Rule (?years : int) = ()
```