# Unexpected keyword 'member' in definition, in a F# module

Tags: f#

Trying to get [optional parameters working in a `module`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56597045/1275774) I tried changing the `let` to `member` and `static member` but that yields errors.

> Error    FS0010  Unexpected keyword 'member' in definition. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

## OK syntax:

```
module Kingdom =
    let Rule years = ()
```

## Bad syntax

```
module Kingdom =
    member this.Rule years = ()
```

Can you not define a `member` in a module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/) states

> Members are features that are part of a **type** definition [...] F# object types such as records, classes, discriminated unions, interfaces, and structures support members.

That's why you cannot define `member` in `module` directly.